# WinForm C# wait 5 second

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2019

For my Win Form program, I need to wait 5 second but the normal c# `Thread.Sleep(5000);` doesn’t work in the Win Form so I tried `Task.Delay(5000);` but it still doesn’t work. Help

```
public void waitThen();
{
    Task.Delay(5000);
    checkForDone();
}
```

Comment: `public async Task waitThen() { await Task.Delay(5000); }` -- The it depends on what `checkForDone();` is doing: You can add `.ConfigureAwait(false)` to the delay, eventually.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Show how you're calling this method etc.

Comment: I just need to wait 5 seconds @mason

Comment: `Task.Delay` is an asynchronous operation.  You need to `await` it.

Comment: *the normal c# Thread.Sleep(5000); doesn’t work in the Win Form* - it does, it just jams the UI

Comment: When I write Thread.Sleep(5000); its says that Thread is not a thing in the curent context

Comment: Then go to the word `Thread` in your code and press Ctrl+<dot> and the IDE will help you

Comment: @Jimi The checkForDone(); is just a messagebox and reset some variables

Comment: @XYink: And did you add `using System.Threading;` to address that?  Much in the same way that `Task` doesn't exist in the current context without `using System.Threading.Tasks;`

Comment: @Jimi er.. can you be sure it's safe to continue on a non UI thread, outside of what you can see here?

Comment: I thought it was there by default

Comment: @CaiusJard *it depends on what `checkForDone();` is doing [...], eventually*

Comment: *I thought it was there by default* - looking at the top of the file would make sure - given that youre getting a complaint, it's probably not!

Comment: @Jimi indeed, which we can't see - I don't think I'd advocate CA(f) here without seeing everything else too

Comment: I can’t check it right now but I know that I didn’t change or add any imports/using so its the default imports/using of a WinForm

Comment: @XYink Don't assume. I've seen many times where a developer is convinced the compiler is wrong but I don't think I've yet seen a situation where they were correct

Comment: @XYink That is why you were asked to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @SirRufo i said it, i cannot check my code right now. I just asked the question. I didn’t think that answers would come that fast.

Comment: @CaiusJard It's something the OP may want to experiment with (and check the Docs about its functionality). I cannot say whether there's something UI related there, but it's not part of the question.

Comment: *I didn’t think that answers would come that fast* - think you might need to upgrade the question then! :D

Comment: Hmm, that's a fairly terrible close duplicate @NicholasCarey

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a long comment thread above, but hopefully an answer can simplify for future visitors...

`Task.Delay` is an asynchronous operation.  (Whether or not it's internally marked as `async` I can't say for sure, but it's "awaitable".)  You just need to `await` it:

```
public async Task waitThen()
{
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    checkForDone();
}
```

Note also that the method now returns a `Task`, **not** `void`.  This makes your `waitThen` method also awaitable, so consuming code will need to await it if that code also wants to wait until the operation is complete before continuing.

---

> but the normal c# `Thread.Sleep(5000);` doesn’t work in the Win Form

Sure it does, it always has.  *However*, unless it's done on a separate thread explicitly then it will also *freeze the UI* for 5 seconds.  Which "works" but is certainly not ideal.  Relying on `Task` is generally the preferred approach.

---

Asides related to the comment thread above:

- In order to use `Task`, you need `using System.Threading.Tasks;`
- In order to use `Thread`, you need `using System.Threading;`
- Method names in C# are traditionally capitalized: `WaitThen`

Comment: You should add the needed `using` statements, because that is one of the troubles the OP has

Comment: And PascalCase the methods, pl0x

Comment: @SirRufo `using` directives, to be pedantic :)